# Do I want an ORM?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, linq-to-xml, sql-server-ce

We have an object model being used across three applications.  Two programs collect data, another reads it and generates reports.  The system is very disconnected, so we cannot have a single database all the programs talk to.

Right now, the programs just use a common library to populate an object model and serialize/deserialize to the disk.  Specifically, we're using XML serialization.

There are a couple problems with this model.  1) XML could be considered wasteful.  The files could get large and unwieldy.  Honestly, file size isn't a huge concern right now.  2)  My biggest concern is memory foot print.  The entire file is loaded into an object model, operated on, then saved.

Hopefully I've conveyed my worry, at some point we will run into memory issues with this application during runtime.  Enough data will get collected into a single "database" (xml file) that it cannot be loaded into memory all at once.

What I would like to have, is access to my object model backed by file storage instead of memory.  I want the changes to the object model to be minimal.  When an object is accessed, it comes from the disk and when it is set, it is saved (automatically, if possible).

We have looked into NHibernate with SQLite, SQL Compact 4.0 and EF 4, and LINQ to XML (briefly).  I've also used db4o in the past for caching objects to disk, but that was an unrelated project.

Before I dive in and commit time to learning one of these, I'd like to know if my idea makes sense.  Can I have an object model that'll "magically" cache to a storage medium instead of just bloating my memory footprint infinitely?  What's the shortest path to get this done, even if it isn't the most elegant?

Are there other technologies that could help me?  Memory mapped files, linq-to-sql, Lazy(T) (for only fetching objects from files when needed possibly).

I realize this is an open ended question.  I'm looking for a big picture response and details if someone out there has real world experience doing this.  Links would be helpful...

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have memory concerns because you work with mobile devices? I ask because I see sql-server-ce as a tag.

Comment: Not mobile right now, looking at SQL Server Compact because it can be embedded in my application (like SQLite).  If we go with EF, SQL Compact will be a consideration as the DB backend.  The memory concerns are due to the fact that it's a 32 bit app, so 2GB limit on the process.

Comment: Is your app a stand alone app.?  It sounds like you don't want a centralized database.  Is the app mulit-user?  How often do you do updates?  How much reporting is done against the application?  These are the types of questions that are importent in making your choice.

Comment: There are 3 standalone applications running on multiple machines in multiple locations.  Once files are manually aggregated (sneaker net).  One of the applications reads the files and creates reports (PPTX with data and images) based on searches performed by the user.  The queries are being written in LINQ against the object model.  So LINQ is the one real requirement I guess.  For now, it's just LINQ to objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just finished migrating a (mostly "inherited") web application backed by XML files to NHibernate exactly out of the same concerns. I also was in the same situation of having never used NHibernate before and wanting to learn in the process.
The idea does make sense. You will indeed be able to load in memory just the parts you actually need (as opposed to the whole DB) and many more benefits than that.

Based on the other things you ask for (minimal changes to your object model, easy to migrate from actual to ORM-based applications) I'm not sure you'll get them so easily.
With ORMs like NHibernate and EF4, model classes are very lightweight: they're basically little more than property containers. Applications based on XML files tend to have more logic directly in the model: that logic you will likely have to move to the data access layer. Redesigning the model and data access layer will likely be the most time consuming task you will face. I know it was for me.

Another thing I infer from your question (you say you can't have all three programs talking to the same DB and you mention SQLite and SQL Compact) is that you're replicating your data among your three applications by copying the file physically. How do you detect changes and how aligned do you need the 3 DBs to be? How do you currently merge changes (in case 2 of the 3 apps you have can write data)?
Depending on how you replicate data, this is something an ORM may or may not help you with.

**Edit**  some more points based on your comments

- If you want at one point to merge the files into one DB and you're not already sure it will be a Microsoft product, then NHibernate is the best choice. But if you are now using LINQ extensively (as per another of your comments) and want a more seamless transition I would go for EF4: Nhibernate.Linq is not really complete and some constructs don't work.
- Both NHibernate and EF4 are very documented and come with very good tutorials on how to build a complete application from scratch, so the learning part is really easy.
- Both have a "model first"  approach where you get a tool that creates your DB for you based on your model classes, so if your model classes are very lightweight you should be able to use them with little modification.
- the thing that took me some time (and still is sometimes hard for me to get working) in NHibernate is configuring cascades to behave the way I expected: e.g. what happens to "related" objects when you delete an object?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that info.  My object model is currently very lightweight.  Each object is just a bunch of properties with some changed events for data binding...so maybe EF or NHibernate will be appropriate.  I'm worried about how long the process of learning either will take.  Both of the products appear complex.  As far as merging goes, I'm not terribly worried about it now.  For the moment we're operating on one file at a time.  Next year there may be an effort to merge files into a central DB.  We've made efforts to make objects uniquely identifiable across files.

Comment: @Nate: instead of answering here in comments I edited my answer directly (too long for a comment...). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the extra info.  I'm digging in deeper to both NH and EF.  I'm finding myself less excited about EF.  The setup seems complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, ORM's map an object model to a relational model.  They do a pretty good job of hiding all the plumbing work that goes into reading and writing data to the database, caching data, managing memory, etc.  They are also very capable of caching parts of an object graph and can do things to improve performance such as lazy loading data.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you use a document database. [RavenDB](http://www.ravendb.net) would give you a lot of benefits. You would be able to store the objects without converting them into a relational model, much like db4o would do.

However, with RavenDB you have a very rich possibility to query the data using Map/Reduce. Another benefit is that it is written using .NET for .NET, so you will enjoy querying in Linq. It can run as a Windows Service or in IIS. It can also run embedded which is great for testing purposes. It might be a good idea for your data collecting applications.

RavenDB also support replication, so that you can store data in one instance and replicate it to another. Maybe that could solve the distributed setup you have.

However, depending of the nature of your distributed setup I think you would be better off using a service bus. Do you need state in the data collecting applications? If not, just publish a message containing the data on the service bus for another part of the system to consume. It might sound complex, but it's actually not. Have a look at [nServicebus](http://www.nservicebus.com).

Comment: RavenDB sounds very interesting.  I like that the format is JSON.  I was turned off by db4o's licensing model.  They wanted a contract per application and the costs were high.  This seems more reasonable.  I may look into it.  As for nServicebus, that sounds interesting as well, maybe something we'll look into next year.  For now, files are copied using sneaker 'net.  Machines are geographically separated and disconnected from any networks.  Next year I may have to put together some sort of "uploader" to be used when the machines come back to the "mothership".